# Is it possible for python to interpret operators within a variable?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a block of text that I am printing to console, and I want to style it a little bit. The block of text is held in a MongoDB, and has a few things included like `colorama` styles and newline characters. I store multiple blocks of text like this in the DB that get called in various ways, and to keep the database clean I'd like to be able to declare everything within 1 field of the document.

Example text block, as seen by python when retrieved using `pymongo`:

```py
'This is the first line of text' + '\n' + Style.DIM + 'This is the second line of text' + '\n'
```

If I put this into `print()`, then it formats exactly as I want where the second line looks greyed out (due to `Style.DIM`):

```
This is the first line of text
This is the second line of text
```

However, if I retrieve it from the database using a `pymongo` call like `db.text["TEXT"]` I can't seem to find the solution for getting python to interpret the `+` operators, newlines or `colorama` styles. It just prints the string literally into the console with single-quotes and all like my first example above.

I've attempted a few things:

- Force it to a string with `str()`
- Try to format with `print(f"{db.text['TEXT']}")`. I entered the newlines and styles within `{}`, but python just printed them literally without parsing anything inside.
- Splitting the text into a list, iterate the list, then print each line. Trying both `str()` and format mentioned previously.

Is there anything built-in that allows me to retrieve the field, then get python to interpret the operators/style/etc before it actually prints to console?

---

EDIT1: Adding code for more context

The MongoDB document looks like this when viewed through `robo3t`:

```json
{
    "_id" : "61e2178b6b5b2246042eac8c",
    "NAME": "Room 1",
    "DESC": "'This is the first line of text' + '\\n' + Style.DIM + 'This is the second line of text' + '\\n'"
}
```

My python looks like this:

```py
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import pymongo

# Setup database connections
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["dbname"]
rooms = db["rooms"]

# I have a lot of docs, so I need to locate the right one first
roomInfo = rooms.find_one( { "NAME": "Room 1" } )

# Now I print the name and description
print(roomInfo["NAME"])
print(roomInfo["DESC"])
```

The output looks like this:

```
Room 1
'This is the first line of text' + '\n' + Style.DIM + 'This is the second line of text' + '\n'
```

---

EDIT2: If I copy the output as it is above into `print()`, it's how I want it to look.

To clarify one more time what I mean, this code:

```
print('This is the first line of text' + '\n' + Style.DIM + 'This is the second line of text' + '\n')
```

Outputs like this:

```
This is the first line of text
This is the second line of text
```

---

EDIT3: Based on @Sid's comment, I tried this:

I updated the document, so it views like this in MongoDB:

```json
# example 1
"DESC": "This is the first line of text\n{Style.DIM}This is the second line of text\n"

# example 2
"DESC": "f\"This is the first line of text\n{Style.DIM}This is the second line of text\n\""
```

I tried `print()` a couple ways:

```py
# example 1
print(f"{roomInfo['DESC']}")

# example 2
print(roomInfo["DESC"])
```

I didn't realize the `\n` characters would get parsed, so that part is solved at least. It still prints the `{}` brackets literally and doesn't parse `Style.DIM` in either example. In the second example, it also prints the `f"` characters.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to store the text in the database? I have a feeling that is where your problem is.

Comment: @JackTaylor Added some context to the end of the question.

Comment: There are a couple of options. The silly and dangerous way is to wrap the text with `print()` and call `eval` on it. A less silly and dangerous way is to write the value of Style.DIM into the text, like `f"<line1>\n{Style.DIM}<line2>\n"` and store that in db.

Comment: @Sid I tried `eval(print(roomInfo['DESC']))`, is that what you meant by the first one?

Comment: @Sid I also added an edit with other things I tried based on your second suggestion. The newlines are parsed, but not `{Style.DIM}`, Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: What Sid means is to do all the work ahead of time, so that the string in the database includes the *actual value of* `Style.DIM`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ahhh, I understand now, and also why it would be considered a bit silly. Could be easily automated, though.

Comment: No no, that's the *less* silly (and actually completely safe) way (which I added to the end of my answer). The silly and (very) dangerous way is that your string in the database starts with `print(` and ends with `)`, and in your code you do something like `eval(roomInfo["DESC"])`. Please do not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a template string in the database, without any operators or string-escapes but with some sort of placeholders for the `.format` call - such that your database object looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "61e2178b6b5b2246042eac8c",
    "NAME": "Room 1",
    "DESC": "This is the first line of text\n{DIM}This is the second line of text\n"
}
```

Ahead of time, construct a mapping from those placeholders to the value to insert:

```py
styles = { 'DIM': Styles.DIM, } # etc.
# There are shortcuts for this, which may or may not be good enough for your purposes.
```

Now when you retrieve a string from the database, you can call `.format` directly (that's one of the reasons why it still exists along-side the f-strings that are syntactic sugar for the method):

```py
roomInfo = rooms.find_one( { "NAME": "Room 1" } )
print(roomInfo['DESC'].format(**styles))
# or: print(roomInfo['DESC'].format_map(styles))
```

You could also do the formatting before you write to the database. That way, the database looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "61e2178b6b5b2246042eac8c",
    "NAME": "Room 1",
    "DESC": "This is the first line of text\n\033[2mThis is the second line of text\n"
}
```

(Of course, in the *code that you use to write to the database*, you'd use an f-string to specify the DIM code.)

This is simpler, but less flexible. By formatting the codes later, you can choose how to format them. You can even easily set it up to ignore all the placeholders:

```py
class Blank(dict):
    """A fake dictionary that reports an empty string for every key."""
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return ''
    # Optional, for cleanliness:
    def __setitem__(self, key):
        pass # intentionally don't add it

# Now every placeholder is just removed - replaced with nothing.
print(roomInfo['DESC'].format_map(Blank()))
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was looking for and makes the fields even easier to maintain. Thanks! Learned something new today about `format`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested this, but maybe try to concatenate the text itself without the “+”, like this

```
f'This is the first line of text/n{Style.DIM}This is the second line of text\n'
```

Comment: I've tried stripping the text of all `+` operators and putting  `Style.DIM` inside `{}` using the `f` method, but unfortunately still prints all characters literally from the database.

Comment: Hold on - *how are you putting things into the database* in the first place? That's what @Jack Taylor was asking you about; that seems to be a cause for confusion here; and I really think you should show it. If you have an f-string in your *code* like this, then it should end up writing already-formatted stuff into your database - assuming that you actually *use code to create the database*. If you create it by editing a .json file or something, then that needs to be clarified as well.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The overall code is somewhat complicated, and I load in json files that I write. Basically a folder of json is my schema, and on a fresh database I load them in. I hadn't considered formatting before loading into the database until I read your other comment. Your initial solution ends up being the best fit as I use these styles in more ways than just some database fields.

Comment: Makes sense. You really don't want to be writing all the `\033[2m` etc. by hand, even if you can get away with hard-coding the values.